# Cannot write a file

Tags: magento-1.9, php, controllers, log, admin-controller

I need to write file by pushing retrieved data in to text file. But the file not write. This is the relevant code section. This code section contains within function in controller.

```
            $filename = "form_ipn.log";
            $fh = fopen($filename, "a") or die("Could not open log file.");
            fwrite($fh, date("d-m-Y, H:i")." - $name;\n") or die("Could not write file!");
            fclose($fh);
```

I have created a file inside a `controller->adminhtml`folder. Is there any problem with this folder regarding writing privileges? Or is there any problem on my code?

Comment: Direct file functions are not recommended in Magento. If you are just after some logging, try `Mage::log` instead.

Comment: yes might be privileges issue as you have not mentioned path of file so it will be default to controller->adminhtml folder. and follow @Prateek's comment as well

Comment: @MineshPatel how to set different path instead of same(admin) folder.

Comment: Yo can specify by like Mage::getBaseDir('media'), Mage::getBaseDir('var');

Comment: For example $filename = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."form_ipn.log"; 
it will write your file in media folder on root

Comment: @MineshPatel Yeah. It works in media folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Converting comments to answer**

yes might be privileges issue as you have not mentioned path of file so it will be default to controller->adminhtml folder

Yo can specify by like

> Mage::getBaseDir('media'), Mage::getBaseDir('var');

For example `$filename = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."form_ipn.log";` it will write your file in media folder on root